# Extracting substring with regex in r, output list with matrix

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I want to extract substrings from a string in r. I tested it with regex101, it does extract the substring I want to have, but it also matches every single other character in my string and gives me a list with a matrix, where it tries to match every single character in the string, but since it only matches a few, I get a lot of empty strings. I would like only the match as a result, no list or matrix or other.

I have a bibliography and want to extract every reference to a volume, an issue or a number (including the following numbers, roman and arabic). So it mathes Volume, Issue and Number 1 as well as I or II. Sometimes thre are multiple of those in my string as well (Volume 3, Issue 2).
Can anyone tell me why it checks every single character?

This is my code so far:

```
string <- 'ABC  (2013c), Something Something Text (Volume II): Some more blabla, the usual, end of string'

pattern <- "[V|v]ol(?:ume)?\\s*(\\d+|(V?I{0,3}X?L?C{0,3}D?M?))|(?:\\s+(Issue|No|Nr|nr|no|Number)\\s*(\\d+|V?I{0,3}X?L?C{0,3}D?M?))?"
  matches <- str_match_all(string , pattern)
```

Comment: First things first, `\s*` must be ``\\s*`` inside a string literal. Second, why do you use `paste(pattern, collapse = "|")`??? Why treat a string as a vector? Even if you just use the string as a pattern, it matches empty strings, so it will match any location before a non-matching char. The second pattern (after `|`) is optional, you must remove the optional outer group.

Comment: I suspect you wanted something like https://regex101.com/r/EkOOtw/1

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/EkOOtw/2 / https://ideone.com/WTZTgX?

Comment: Nice, this solves it! Thank you! So the word boundary is the thing that makes it not check every single character?

Comment: No. A pattern that does not match an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that your pattern part after `|` is wrapped with an optional non-capturing group and even if all other typos are fixed, that problem still needs to be resolved.

The number matching part is the same on both ends of the OR operator, so you can merge both alternatives into one and simply use

```r
string <- 'ABC  (2013c), Something Something Text (Volume II): Some more blabla, the usual, end of string'
 
rx <- paste0("\\b(?:[Vv]ol(?:ume)?|Issue|No|Nr|nr|no|Number)\\s*(?:\\d+|V?I{0,3}X?L?C{0,3}D?M?)")
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(string, rx)
## => [[1]]
##    [1] "Volume II"
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/WTZTgX)

The pattern will look like

```
\b(?:[Vv]ol(?:ume)?|Issue|No|Nr|nr|no|Number)\s*(?:\d+|V?I{0,3}X?L?C{0,3}D?M?)
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EkOOtw/2). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:[Vv]ol(?:ume)?|Issue|No|Nr|nr|no|Number)` - `vol`, `Vol`, `volume`, `Volume`, `Issue`, `No`, `Nr`, `nr`, `no` or `Number`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(?:\d+|V?I{0,3}X?L?C{0,3}D?M?)` - one or more digits or an optional `V`, then zero to three `I`s, then an optional `X`, an optional `L`, a C zero to three occurrences and then an optional `D` and an optional `M`.